# Gatsby site not rendering in IE 11

Tags: gatsby

I've created a new site using the https://github.com/codebushi/gatsby-starter-photon template, and I've upgraded to the latest version of Node.js (12.16.1) and the latest Gatsby (2.20.1), but I can't get the site to render in IE or the original Edge browsers. I've tried a ton of things I've found on the net, and I'm injecting polyfill.js as well. In fact, I've tried injecting another polyfill directly into the system to support "forEach", but I'm still getting a blank page, and the following error:

`Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'`

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was nothing to do with Photon - I'd incorporated a component from somewhere else, so there was indeed a "forEach" in my own user code. The I.E. browser tools showed me where by clicking on the error to get a stack trace, and I had to change:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".navbar li").forEach(function (elem) { 
    elem.onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("topnav").classList.remove("open");
    };
});
```

into

```
var liElements = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar li");
        for (let i = 0; i < liElements.length; i++) {
            const elem = liElements[i];

            elem.onclick = function() {
                document.getElementById("topnav").classList.remove("open");
            };
        }
```

then it all worked fine. Hopefully that can help someone else.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify browsers support in package.json:

```
{
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
}
```

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-support/

**But** maybe you don't need to do this. Gatsby in development mode doesn't work right on IE `npm run develop`, but meanwhile `npm run build` is working fine - you can test it with `gastby serve` after building.

Comment: Hi. I've tried this also, and it's not working:

"browserslist": [
 ">1%",
 "not dead",
 "IE 11"
  ]

I've tried without those as well of course. I've read that it won't work in dev, and that's annoying but not the end of the world - this is not working in Prod either (gatsby build then gatsby serve) or live on the internet. Incidentally, I've got this with a "normal" gatsby site and the same with a Docz site - neither is working in IE 11, or with the original (pre-Chromium) Edge)